# NIS - Proper Format for Multiple Hosts

Tags: nis

I'm very new to working with NIS and have been tasked with reorganizing the files. Which is the proper delimiter that should be used for a NIS file with this format:

```
username    server1:server2:server3
```

OR

```
username    server1,server2,server3
```

OR

```
username    server1 server2 server3
```

OR

```
Some other solution
```

The file is used to mark what servers the user can have access too. I just want to know what the standard format is for these files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why NIS and not ldap?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what is the name of the file you are talking about?

NIS is incredibly insecure, if you are supposed to be managing it I'd make my first priory how I could manage to get rid of it, you can move most NIS settings directly to most LDAP servers (there is a NIS schema in most of they by default).

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-nis.html has some good information on NIS.